# HTTP live streaming from android device to amazon web server S3

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg, java-native-interface, http-live-streaming

I want to stream a video being capture by an android device to an amazon S3 server. Is it possible only in java or I have to use JNI and FFMPEG. Any sample code or online tutorial/Link. Help plz.

Comment: It's possible, but you haven't provided nearly enough information.  Start by specifying what codecs you need to support.

Comment: Any codec supported by default by Android devices and can also be played on iOS device like 3gp or mp4.

Comment: I have been searching for the same thing over a week now. Can you help me here  with this
?

Answer (score 1):

HTTP live streaming I have implemented involve recording a video file (mp4 or other) then add its link to an index.m3u8 file and then upload both in a tic toc fashion.

[Here is a project](https://github.com/chrisballinger/FFmpeg-iOS-Encoder/tree/master/FFmpegEncoder/Android)

which I use to get the basic logic and modified it according to my need. This is the class which will upload your file to AWS S3

```
package com.example.ffmpegtest;

import java.io.File;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ProgressEvent;
import com.readystatesoftware.simpl3r.Uploader;
import com.readystatesoftware.simpl3r.Uploader.UploadProgressListener;

public class S3Client {
    private static final String TAG = "S3Client";

    AmazonS3Client s3;
    Context c;

    String bucket;

    public interface S3Callback{
        public void onProgress(ProgressEvent progressEvent, long bytesUploaded, int percentUploaded);
    }

    public S3Client(Context c, String AWS_KEY, String AWS_SECRET){
        s3 = new AmazonS3Client(new BasicAWSCredentials(SECRETS.AWS_KEY, SECRETS.AWS_SECRET));
        this.c = c;
    }

    /**
     * Set the target S3 bucket of this client. 
     * Must be set before calling upload.
     * @param bucket The name of the target S3 bucket.
     */
    public void setBucket(String bucket){
        this.bucket = bucket;
    }

    /**
     * Begin an upload to S3. Returns the url to the completed upload.
     * @param key Path relative to provided S3 bucket.
     * @param source File reference to be uploaded.
     * @param callback Callback providing upload progress.
     * @return
     */
    public String upload(String key, File source, final S3Callback callback){
        if(bucket == null){
            Log.e(TAG, "Bucket not set! Call setBucket(String bucket)");
            return "";
        }
        Uploader uploader = new Uploader(c, s3, bucket, key, source);
        uploader.setProgressListener(new UploadProgressListener() {         
            @Override
            public void progressChanged(ProgressEvent progressEvent, 
                    long bytesUploaded, int percentUploaded) {
                if(callback != null)
                    callback.onProgress(progressEvent, bytesUploaded, percentUploaded);
            }
        });
        return uploader.start();        
    }


}
```

you can take a look at HLSRecorder and HLSObserver to continuously recording and checking the directory in which you placing the recorded file so you can upload them when they complete.

Your index.m3u8 file will look like this

```
    #EXTM3U
#EXTINF:5.0,
http://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/your.bukect.name/filename1.mp4
#EXTINF:5.0,
http://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/your.bukect.name/filename2.mp4
```

5.0 is the video duration which is 5 second in my case.